# Configure Shared Access Signature on Azure Service Bus Subscription

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

From the Microsoft documentation, I see that SAS can be scoped to only Azure Service Bus Namespaces, Queues, Topics and not Subscriptions. I have a use case where I want the consumers of one subscription to not be able to access other subscriptions. If Azure Service bus currently doesn't support it, how do I implement this?

Comment: I provided this answer to a similar question - don't know if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152952/azure-servicebus-sas-key-for-a-subscription/47175989#47175989

Answer (score 1):

If using a managed identity or a service principal is an option for you, then Azure RBAC does support fine-grained access. Please check the docs in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity#azure-built-in-roles-for-azure-service-bus). Example:

```
az role assignment create \
    --role $service_bus_role \
    --assignee $assignee_id \
    --scope /subscriptions/$subscription_id/resourceGroups/$resource_group/providers/Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/$service_bus_namespace/topics/$service_bus_topic/subscriptions/$service_bus_subscription
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible and the same is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#shared-access-authorization-policies) as well.

While [generating the signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#generate-a-shared-access-signature-token), you would just need to use the resource URI for the subscription like this

```
https://<yournamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/myTopic/Subscriptions/mySubscription
```

You can check the scopes for the different [rights required for service bus operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#rights-required-for-service-bus-operations) in the docs.

Here is a [.NET Framework Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-Shared-Access-e605b37c) for reference. (Thanks @Roberto!)

Comment: In fact, the answer for this question is in the link that Pramod provided, just pointing directly:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-Shared-Access-e605b37c

Comment: Thanks! I will include this in the answer for better visibility. Note that the sample is for .NET Framework.

Comment: @RobertoBorges That sample seems to have disappeared. I tried looking in the https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus repo, but no luck. Any idea where this sample has gone to?

Comment: @Thorarin, I didn't test yet, but this sample seems to work as well for this problem: https://github.com/clemensv/service-bus-activedirectory-sas-function

Comment: Looks like it has been archived here: https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-community-s-z/tree/master/Using%20Shared%20Access%20Signature%20(SAS)%20authentication%20with%20ServiceBus%20Subscriptions